# Use a Vue JS component method in another vue comonent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a two different vue component files, what should i do in order to use a `changeCollection()` method from **Check-list.vue** in another **Component.vue** file?

**Check-lust.vue**:

```
<template lang="html" ref="">
  <div class="check-list-view">
    <collections :current_collection="this.current_collection" ></collections>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      current_collection: 'All'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeCollection (collname) {
      this.current_collection = collname
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And **Component.vue**:

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="container " style="margin-bottom:32px">
    <!-- NOT WORKS: -->
    <button type="button" name="button" class="btn my-btn-orange" @click="changeCollection('All')">All</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  props: ['current_collection']
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Define a mixin.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)

**mixin.js**

```
export default {
  methods: {
    changeCollection(collname) {
      this.current_collection = collname
    }
  }
}
```

**Check-lust.vue:**

```
<template lang="html" ref="">
  <div class="check-list-view">
    <!-- changeCollection should be available here now -->
    <collections @click="changeCollection">hello world</collections>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import mixin from './mixin.js' //import the mixin
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      current_collection: 'All'
    }
  },
  mixins:[mixin], // include the mixin in your component
  methods: {
    changeCollection (collname) {
      this.current_collection = collname
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

repeat the import of `mixin.js` on the rest of your components, and define `mixins` property on those as well.

`ChangeCollection` will be available on each component.

Comment: Can I realize that without mixins, only using $refs ?

Comment: that's absolutely not the use case of $refs